# Is it possible to use PHP to compare two posts and when the title matches, get the ID of the post?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

First a bit of context to understand what I'm doing. I'm using WordPress. So I have a page with a list of texts in Latin. These items (the titles and excerpts) are automatically posted on the page (sort of like a blog page), and the texts themselves are posts in the WordPress back-end. I have a category "text" and a category "translation" to separate the two types of content.

When I click on one text, I get sent to a detail page where the full text can be read. When the link is clicked, the ID of that post is stored in a $GLOBALS variable. That variable is then called on the detail page to show the entire content of the text. I used an AJAX call to store the variable. And this is how I post the contents on the detail page:

```
<div class="left">
 <?php
    $post_id = $GLOBALS['post_id'];
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    $title = $queried_post->post_title;
    $content = $queried_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
 ?>
 <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
 <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
```

What I want to do is show the translation of each text on the same detail page in a second column (the css is no problem). I tried a few things like this:

```
<div class="right">
 <?php
    $post_id_two = ???
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id_two);
$title_two = $queried_post->post_title;
    $content_two = $queried_post->post_content;
    $content_two = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content_two = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
 ?>
 <h3><?php echo $title_two; ?></h3>
 <p><?php echo $content_two; ?></p>
```

But I just can't figure out how to compare the second post title to the first one and the show the correct translation on the corresponding detail page. If there is an easier way to do this, anything is welcome.

Comment: Is the translation stored in a database or computed in runtime?

Comment: Stored in the same database, they're also just wordpress posts (but seperated from the text posts by setting another category)

Comment: If there's a relation between both ids, you can find the translated text using the id of the original one

Comment: there isn't really a link between the id's... the title is the same for both posts but as far as I know the id's are just randomly generated by WordPress

Comment: It's actually sequential, but since there are so many things that get a post ID other than posts (drafts, auto-drafts, revisions, attachments, even customizer css), it's not really possible to predict what post ID you'll be working with in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an easier approach to this might be to add a custom meta box that allows you to store the post ID of the translation text as meta data to the post with the Latin text. Here's a kind of crude way to do it, but you'll at least get the idea:

Add this to functions.php in your theme or to a plugin. (a plugin is preferred for this type of stuff)

```
//Define the contents of your meta box
function prefix_meta_box_contents($post){
    $current_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'prefix_translation_post', true);
    ?>
    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $current_value; ?>" min="0" name="prefix_translation_post">
    <?php
}

//Save the meta data
add_action('save_post', 'prefix_save_translation_post_meta');
function prefix_save_translation_post_meta($post_id){
    if(array_key_exists('prefix_translation_post',$_POST)){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'prefix_translation_post', $_POST['prefix_translation_post'] );
    }
}

//Hook onto the add_meta_boxes action
add_action('add_meta_boxes','prefix_meta_box');
function prefix_meta_box(){
    //Register the box
    add_meta_box('prefix_translation_post_mb','Translation Post','prefix_meta_box_contents');
}
```

Then go to your Latin text post and tell it the ID number of the post that contains the translation. Save that, then try using this for your translated text column:

```
<div class="right">
 <?php
    $post_id_two = get_post_meta($queried_post->ID, 'prefix_translation_post', true);
    $queried_post_two = get_post($post_id_two);
    $title_two = $queried_post_two->post_title;
    $content_two = $queried_post_two->post_content;
    $content_two = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content_two = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
 ?>
 <h3><?php echo $title_two; ?></h3>
 <p><?php echo $content_two; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it and if it all works, mark this as the answer :)

Comment: I guess $post_id would work as well instead of $queried_post->ID in the get_post_meta function since you'll have already set that variable previously.

Comment: Oops, forgot some quotes. Let me know if it doesn't work. It should

Comment: I'm not quite there yet... the first part seems to work fine (I see the meta box and can fill it in) but for some weird reason it posts the Latin text again where it should show the translation?

Edit: in the second part I changed all of the "$queried_post" starting from the php second line to "$queried_post_two" and that solved the problem. So now everything works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: Oh ok, good catch. I edited my post. Not really sure why that's needed to be honest haha, but I'm glad it's working for you

Comment: I assumed it was because the $queried_post variable already contained the first post, but who knows... 'If it ain't broke,...' I guess ;)

Comment: Yea, but I would assume that it would be overridden when you call a new post to it. Obviously not, just don't know why. Weird